# When attempting to use Import-Clixml on a List<T>, the return value is System.Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Here is a  simplified and complete code example:

```
class DediInfo {
    [string]$ServiceName
    [int]$QueryPort

    DediInfo([string]$servicename, [int]$qPort){
        $this.ServiceName = $servicename
        $this.QueryPort = $qPort
    }
}

class DediInfos {
    hidden static [DediInfos] $_instance = [DediInfos]::new()
    static [DediInfos] $Instance = [DediInfos]::GetInstance()
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[DediInfo]]$Dedis = [System.Collections.Generic.List[DediInfo]]::New()

    hidden static [DediInfos] GetInstance() {
        return [DediInfos]::_instance
    }

    [void]SaveInfo(){
        $this.Dedis | Export-Clixml "D:\test.xml"
    }

    [void]LoadInfo() {
        $this.Dedis = Import-Clixml "D:\test.xml"
    }

}

$dInfos = [DediInfos]::Instance
$dInfos.Dedis.Add([DediInfo]::New("service1", 15800))
$dInfos.Dedis.Add([DediInfo]::New("service2", 15801))
$dInfos.SaveInfo()
$dInfos.Dedis = [System.Collections.Generic.List[DediInfo]]::New()
$dInfos.LoadInfo()
```

And here is the Exception I am receiving:

```
Exception setting "Dedis": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DediInfo]"."
At D:\test.ps1:25 char:9
+         $this.Dedis = Import-Clixml "D:\test.xml"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

I've spent the past 4 hours trying different permutations:

- adding `[Serializable()]` to the first class
- using the `ConvertTo-Xml` on the `List<>` before saving and after reading from file
- breaking out the load steps to dump into a new list first - which does load the data from file, but I can't put it back to the singleton's List<> because it loads as `System.Object`
- Tried using saving to json (below) and same error message
- - `$this.Dedis | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content "D:\test.json"`
- - `$this.Dedis = Get-Content -Raw "D:\test.json" | ConvertFrom-Json`
- Lots of other attempts that I cannot remember any longer.

What I'm wanting is just a way to save the `List<>` to a file and then load it back in again  on my next script's run. The example is very simplified; it saves, clears, and then tries to load again to show what I'm dealing with. Everywhere I've read is that the Import-Clixml should load the XML file back in as the original object, but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Import-XML` indeed load back the object, but does not quite respect the type.
Prior export, you had a list of DediInfo objects.
After import, you now have an array of `Deserialized.DediInfo` objects.

You can see that by doing an import and checking the base type of the first dediinfo object.

```
$Imported = Import-Clixml "D:\test.xml"
$Imported[0].psobject.TypeNames
```

It will show

```
Deserialized.DediInfo
Deserialized.System.Object
```

Hence, your conversion is failing because you are trying to cast it back to its original type, which is not possible.

You will have to build your list of DediInfo again after importing the XML.
Here's a simple modification to your `LoadInfo` that will work.

```
    [void]LoadInfo() {
        $this.Dedis = Foreach ($i in  Import-Clixml "D:\test.xml") {
            [DediInfo]::New($i.ServiceName, $i.QueryPort)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing after posting this. I was kind of hoping I wouldn't have to specify the the .property name for every field that was loaded in.

Comment: @вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞвєнᴎєƞ Technically you can and depending on your need that might be enough. If you change the type of your `$Dedis` from a list of casted object (DediInfo) to a generic object, like this `    [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]$Dedis = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::New()`. That way, both 'DediInfo' and 'Deserialized.DediInfo' will work. Provided that nothing down the line attempt to typecast the object back to a DediInfo, all the properties / methods will be good.

Comment: I'd rather have the strongly typed property names rather than keeping it as a generic object. The load method and class descriptor are kept in the same file; I just wrote a BIG COMMENT at the top of the file and above the load method to remind me that I need to specify all properties in the load method if I make any changes.